# Move the background image of ::before element to the bottom

Tags: html, css

I want to move the background image of `header::before`'s background image to the bottom of the header. But it's stuck on the top. Here is the design I want to achieve.

[image]

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700&family=Raleway:wght@400;700&display=swap");
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*>img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

:root {
  --main-bg: hsl(218, 28%, 13%);
  --intro-bg: hsl(217, 28%, 15%);
  --footer-bg: hsl(216, 53%, 9%);
  --testimonial-bg: hsl(219, 30%, 18%);
  --error: hsl(0, 100%, 63%);
  --text-clr: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  color: var(--text-clr);
  background: var(--main-bg);
  background-size: cover;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

nav {
  background: var(--intro-bg);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

nav a .logo {
  max-width: 5rem;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: var(--text-clr);
  text-decoration: none;
}

header {
  background: var(--intro-bg);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
}

header img {
  max-width: 350px;
}

header::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRLMl4_ScwHun3sWMAmlDsshDOzMCpJIWXsXQ&usqp=CAU) no-repeat;
  z-index: -1;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Logo</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Features</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Team</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sign In</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
<header>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9a/Gull_portrait_ca_usa.jpg">
  <h1>A random header</h1>
  <p>I want to position the header in the bottom. But it's stuck on the top.</p>
  <button>Get Started</button>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for the `background-position` property?

```
background-position: bottom 0px center;
```

And if you want it to cover the full background size, just add :

```
background-size:100%;
```

Comment: Yes sir. Can you tell me how to increase the height of background image?

Comment: You can change the size of the background image with the `background-size` property